# Send audio data to ibm watson speech recognizer using OpenSL ES

Tags: java, android, c++, speech-recognition, opensl

I am currently using OpenSL ES to get audio data from the local device's microphone. I am using a PipedStream to send the audio data to the ibm watson speech recognizer using websocket but I am not getting any results and I am not entirely sure why. I need help to get the results using the microphone.

This is my MainActivity.java

```
PipedInputStream pipedInputStream;
PipedOutputStream pipedOutputStream;

MyDataHandler handler;

SpeechToText speechToTextService;
String result;
Boolean isFinal;

AudioFormat audioFormat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        pipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream();
        pipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream(pipedOutputStream);
        handler = new MyDataHandler(pipedOutputStream);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                start_process();
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    doCallToNativeFunction(pipedOutputStream);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();

        speechToTextService = new SpeechToText();
        speechToTextService.setUsernameAndPassword("f1361112-2e3e-4787-b180-4df70aee83a1",
                "BCouSNYeaqtc");

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                RecognizeOptions options = new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
                        .continuous(true)
                        .interimResults(true)
                        .contentType(HttpMediaType.AUDIO_PCM + "; rate=" + 44100)
                        .inactivityTimeout(-1)
                        .wordConfidence(true)
                        .build();
                speechToTextService.recognizeUsingWebSocket(pipedInputStream, options, new BaseRecognizeCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTranscription(SpeechResults speechResults) {
                        try {
                            result = speechResults.getResults().get(0).getAlternatives()
                                    .get(0).getTranscript();
                            isFinal = speechResults.getResults().get(0).isFinal();

                            System.out.println(speechResults);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

public void doCallToNativeFunction(OutputStream outputStream) {
    getAudioDataWithHandler(handler);
}
```

DataHandler.java

```
OutputStream dataStream;

public MyDataHandler(OutputStream writeTo) {
    dataStream = writeTo;
}
public void handleData(byte[] incomingData) {
    try {
        dataStream.write(incomingData, 0, incomingData.length);
        dataStream.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MyDataHandler", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

MainSystem.cpp

```
OPENSL_STREAM *p;
int samps, i, j;
float inbuffer[VECSAMPS_MONO], outbuffer[VECSAMPS_STEREO];

static int on;
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
start_process() {
p = android_OpenAudioDevice(SR, 1, 1, BUFFERFRAMES);
if (p == NULL) return;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
stop_process() {
on = 0;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
getAudioDataWithHandler(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                    jclass 
clazz,
                                                                    jobject 
obj) {

if (p != NULL) {
    samps = android_AudioIn(p, inbuffer, VECSAMPS_MONO);

    jbyteArray audioDataCopy = env->NewByteArray(samps);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(audioDataCopy, 0, samps, (jbyte *) inbuffer);

    jmethodID aMethodId = env->GetMethodID(env->GetObjectClass(obj), "handleData", "([B)V");
    assert(0 != aMethodId);
    env->CallVoidMethod(obj, aMethodId, audioDataCopy);
} else {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "s", "NULL");
}
}
```

OpenSLSystem.cpp

```
static void *createThreadLock(void);
static void   waitThreadLock(void *lock);
static void  notifyThreadLock(void *lock);
static void  destroyThreadLock(void *lock);
static void  bqRecorderCallback(SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf bq, void 
*context);

static void openSLCreateEngine(OPENSL_STREAM *p) {
SLresult result;

result = slCreateEngine(&(p->engineObject), 0 , NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
assert(result == SL_RESULT_SUCCESS);

result = (*p->engineObject)->Realize(p->engineObject, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
assert(result == SL_RESULT_SUCCESS);

result = (*p->engineObject)->GetInterface(p->engineObject, SL_IID_ENGINE, &(p->engineEngine));
assert(result == SL_RESULT_SUCCESS);
}

static void openSLRecOpen(OPENSL_STREAM *p) {

SLresult result;
SLuint32 sr = p->sr;
SLuint32 channels = p->inchannels;

if (channels) {
    switch(sr) {
        case 8000:
            sr = SL_SAMPLINGRATE_8;
            break;
        case 11025:
            sr = SL_SAMPLINGRATE_11_025;
            break;
        case 16000:
            sr = SL_SAMPLINGRATE_16;
            break;
        case 22050:
            sr = SL_SAMPLINGRATE_22_05;
            break;
        case 24000:
            sr = SL_SAMPLINGRATE_24;
            break;
        case 32000:
            sr = SL_SAMPLINGRATE_32;
            break;
        case 44100:
            sr = SL_SAMPLINGRATE_44_1;
            break;
        case 64000:
            sr = SL_SAMPLINGRATE_64;
            break;
        case 88200:
            sr = SL_SAMPLINGRATE_88_2;
            break;
        case 96000:
            sr = SL_SAMPLINGRATE_96;
            break;
        case 192000:
            sr = SL_SAMPLINGRATE_192;
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }

    SLDataLocator_IODevice loc_dev = {SL_DATALOCATOR_IODEVICE, SL_IODEVICE_AUDIOINPUT,
                                      SL_DEFAULTDEVICEID_AUDIOINPUT, NULL};
    SLDataSource audioSrc = {&loc_dev, NULL};

    SLuint32 speakers;
    if (channels > 1)
        speakers = SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_LEFT | SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_RIGHT;
    else speakers = SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_CENTER;
    SLDataLocator_AndroidSimpleBufferQueue loc_bq = 
{SL_DATALOCATOR_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE, 2};
    SLDataFormat_PCM format_pcm = {SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM, channels, sr,
                                   SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_8, 
SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_8,
                                   speakers, SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN};
    SLDataSink audioSnk = {&loc_bq, &format_pcm};

    const SLInterfaceID id[1] = {SL_IID_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE};
    const SLboolean req[1] = {SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE};
    result = (*p->engineEngine)->CreateAudioRecorder(p->engineEngine, &(p->recorderObject), &audioSrc,
                                                     &audioSnk, 1, id, req);
    assert(result == SL_RESULT_SUCCESS);

    result = (*p->recorderObject)->Realize(p->recorderObject, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
    assert(result == SL_RESULT_SUCCESS);

    result = (*p->recorderObject)->GetInterface(p->recorderObject, SL_IID_RECORD, &(p->recorderRecord));
    assert(result == SL_RESULT_SUCCESS);

    result = (*p->recorderObject)->GetInterface(p->recorderObject, SL_IID_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE,
                                               &(p->recorderBufferQueue));
    assert(result == SL_RESULT_SUCCESS);

    result = (*p->recorderBufferQueue)->RegisterCallback(p->recorderBufferQueue, bqRecorderCallback,
                                                         p);
    assert(result == SL_RESULT_SUCCESS);

    result = (*p->recorderRecord)->SetRecordState(p->recorderRecord, SL_RECORDSTATE_RECORDING);
    assert(result == SL_RESULT_SUCCESS);
}
}

static void openSLDestroyEngine(OPENSL_STREAM *p) {
    if (p->recorderObject != NULL) {
        (*p->recorderObject)->Destroy(p->recorderObject);
        p->recorderObject = NULL;
        p->recorderRecord = NULL;
        p->recorderBufferQueue = NULL;
    }

    if (p->engineObject != NULL) {
        (*p->engineObject)->Destroy(p->engineObject);
        p->engineObject = NULL;
        p->engineEngine = NULL;
    }
}
OPENSL_STREAM *android_OpenAudioDevice(int sr, int inchannels, int outchannels, int bufferframes) {
OPENSL_STREAM *p;
p = (OPENSL_STREAM *) calloc(sizeof(OPENSL_STREAM), 1);

p->inchannels = inchannels;
p->outchannels = outchannels;
p->sr = sr;
p->inlock = createThreadLock();
p->outlock = createThreadLock();

if ((p->outBufSamples = bufferframes * outchannels) != 0) {
    if ((p->outputBuffer[0] = (short *) calloc(p->outBufSamples, sizeof(short))) == NULL ||
            (p->outputBuffer[1] = (short *) calloc(p->outBufSamples, sizeof(short))) == NULL) {
        android_CloseAudioDevice(p);
        return NULL;
    }
}

if ((p->inBufSamples = bufferframes * inchannels) != 0) {
    if ((p->inputBuffer[0] = (short *) calloc(p->inBufSamples, sizeof(short))) == NULL ||
            (p->inputBuffer[1] = (short *) calloc(p->inBufSamples, sizeof(short))) == NULL) {
        android_CloseAudioDevice(p);
        return NULL;
    }
}

p->currentInputIndex = 0;
p->currentOutputBuffer = 0;
p->currentInputIndex = p->inBufSamples;
p->currentInputBuffer = 0;

openSLCreateEngine(p);
openSLRecOpen(p);

notifyThreadLock(p->outlock);
notifyThreadLock(p->inlock);

p->time = 0.;
return p;
}

void android_CloseAudioDevice(OPENSL_STREAM *p) {
if (p == NULL)
    return;

openSLDestroyEngine(p);

if (p->inlock != NULL) {
    notifyThreadLock(p->inlock);
    destroyThreadLock(p->inlock);
    p->inlock = NULL;
}

if (p->outlock != NULL) {
    notifyThreadLock(p->outlock);
    destroyThreadLock(p->outlock);
    p->outlock = NULL;
}

if (p->outputBuffer[0] != NULL) {
    free(p->outputBuffer[0]);
    p->outputBuffer[0] = NULL;
}

if (p->outputBuffer[1] != NULL) {
    free(p->outputBuffer[1]);
    p->outputBuffer[1] = NULL;
}

if (p->inputBuffer[0] != NULL) {
    free(p->inputBuffer[0]);
    p->inputBuffer[0] = NULL;
}

if (p->inputBuffer[1] != NULL) {
    free(p->inputBuffer[1]);
    p->inputBuffer[1] = NULL;
}

free(p);
}

void bqRecorderCallback(SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf bq, void *context) {
OPENSL_STREAM *p = (OPENSL_STREAM *) context;
notifyThreadLock(p->inlock);
}

int android_AudioIn(OPENSL_STREAM *p, float *buffer, int size) {
    short *inBuffer;
    int i, bufsamps = p->inBufSamples, index = p->currentInputIndex;
    if (p == NULL || bufsamps == 0) return 0;

    inBuffer = p->inputBuffer[p->currentInputBuffer];
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (index >= bufsamps) {
            waitThreadLock(p->inlock);
            (*p->recorderBufferQueue)->Enqueue(p->recorderBufferQueue,
                                              inBuffer, bufsamps * sizeof(short));
            p->currentInputBuffer = (p->currentInputBuffer ? 0 : 1);
            index = 0;
            inBuffer = p->inputBuffer[p->currentInputBuffer];
        }
        buffer[i] = (float) inBuffer[index++] *CONVMYFLT;
    }
    p->currentInputIndex = index;
    if (p->outchannels == 0) p->time += (double) size / (p->sr * p->inchannels);
    return i;
}
void *createThreadLock(void) {
    threadLock *p;
    p = (threadLock *) malloc(sizeof(threadLock));
    if (p == NULL)
        return NULL;
    memset(p, 0, sizeof(threadLock));
    if (pthread_mutex_init(&(p->m), (pthread_mutexattr_t *) NULL) != 0) {
        free((void *) p);
        return NULL;
    }
    if (pthread_cond_init(&(p->c), (pthread_condattr_t *) NULL) != 0) {
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&(p->m));
        free((void *) p);
        return NULL;
    }
    p->s = (unsigned char) 1;

    return p;
}


void waitThreadLock(void *lock) {
    threadLock *p;
    int __unused retval = 0;
    p = (threadLock *) lock;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(p->m));
    while (!p->s) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&(p->c), &(p->m));
    }
    p->s = (unsigned char) 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(p->m));
}
void notifyThreadLock(void *lock) {
    threadLock *p;
    p = (threadLock *) lock;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(p->m));
    p->s = (unsigned char) 1;
    pthread_cond_signal(&(p->c));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(p->m));
}

void destroyThreadLock(void *lock) {
    threadLock *p;
    p = (threadLock *) lock;
    if (p == NULL)
        return;
    notifyThreadLock(p);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&(p->c));
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&(p->m));
    free(p);
}
```

**Update01**

So I played the data to the speakers of my device and it is just playing a bunch of clicking noises, so it is definitely coming down to the audio data.

**Update02**

I printed out the array while it was reading the audio data and it is printing out the same buffer. So I am guessing that the way my system is structured it is not getting a new buffer from the microphone for some reason.